# Sharepoint 2013 built in date validation

Tags: date-time, validation

I'm trying to use the 2013 built in date validation. I want to make sure the date entered into the GoLive Date is not more that 10 days in the past.

`=[GoLive Date]>[GoLive Date]-10`

How can I turn this into a true/false statement?

Comment: You can use JSLink on Date field on edit and New form. Apply JSlink , Fetch Date field  , Check the value of field and throw user friendly message using JQuery.

Comment: Reference for date validation using JSLink  :  http://www.edinkapic.com/2007/10/add-javascript-date-validation-into.html

Comment: Hi Dipen, thanks for the tip, but I'm wanting to use the built in validation so it works with the data sheet view as well and new, edit forms.

Comment: I'll  look  more for  the  same  and  answer  u shortly. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **not** reference other Columns in a **Column** validation,
so

```
=[Due Date]>[Created]-10
```

or

```
=[date1]>([date2]-10)
```

do **not** work (but can be used in the **Form** Validation: *List Settings-> Validation Settings*)

In a Column validation you can use the `Today()` *function*

**date not older than 10 days in the past**

```
=[Due Date]>Today()-10
```

Comment: I see now that doing my original calculation was comparing a value that hadn't been set. The today function will help me out here, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it = [date1] > ([date2] - 10)